# LibGdx doesn't working after updating Gradle (Android Studio 3.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I have recently updated android studio and gradle to the version 3.0.0 following instructions in this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

After doing this libgdx desktop project doesn't work.

It give me this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
```

Here is build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
```

I only added `google()` to repositories and edit gradle version to `3.0.0`

In `gradle-wrapper.properties` I added this line

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: How do you run your application? Edit Configuration -> Press + -> Click Gradle -> desktop:run in Tasks input and try to run please.

Comment: I run it as follow edit configurations - New application (java) - choose desktop launcher and assets folder as working directory - finally run but it gives me that error

Comment: Could you try it with my way?

Comment: I have this same problem, but I can successfully run it from the CLI using ./gradlew desktop:run

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android Studio `3.0` using `gradle-4.1` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0`

`Gradle 4.1` is not supported yet in LibGDX, there is an [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4698) for the same, which is now [upgraded](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5177) for Gradle 4.6

Currently **html module** using deprecated `jetty` plugin which is removed in `Gradle 4.1` version.

However using Terminal you can run desktop module, I've not tested on windows but on Mac it's working fine.

```
./gradlew desktop:run
```

---

For now you can use lower version of `Gradle` and `Andoid-gradle-plugin` in Android Studio 3.0 and wait for issue to be fixed.

- Downgrade Gradle version from 4.1 to 3.3

  Find gradle folder inside your project, Open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change distributionUrl for 3.3

  ```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
  ```
- Downgrade Android-gradle-plugin version from 3.0.0 to 2.3.3

  Open root `build.gradle` file and find artifact in buildscript and 
  change version

  ```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
  ```
- Comment/delete `google()` from repo list inside root `build.gradle` file

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT** : Update LibGDX project to Gradle 4.6 - AS USER

1. Upgrade Gradle to 4.6 :

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
   ```
2. Add Google's Maven repo in project repositories list as well as in buildScript repo list in root `build.gradle` file.

   ```
   repositories {
       //.. 
       google()
       jcenter()         // Required for org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j library
   }
   ```
3. Update Android Gradle Plugin :

   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`

   **Known issues with the Android Gradle Plugin**

   > Configuration on demand with Gradle 4.6 and above:
   >
   > If you're using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.x or 3.1.x with Gradle 4.6
   >   and above, you should disable configuration on demand to avoid some
   >   unpredictable build errors. (If you are using Android Gradle Plugin
   >   3.2.0 or higher, you do not need to take any action to disable configuration on demand.)

   Disable configuration on demand in your `gradle.properties` file as shown below:

   - `org.gradle.configureondemand=false`
   - To disable configuration on demand in the Android Studio settings, choose File > Settings (Android Studio > Preferences on Mac), select the Compiler category in the left pane, and clear the Configure on demand checkbox.

     In Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1 and higher, the options for enabling configuration on demand have been removed.
4. Update Android buildToolsVersion to `27.0.3` and SdkVersion to `27`
5. Remove `instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')`  from `sourceSets` inside android `build.gradle` file
6. replace all `compile` with `implementation` inside root `build.gradle` file
7. New `GWT Gradle Plugin` added in html module, check latest [build.gradle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-gwt/build.gradle) of html module.

Run your project with `Run Configuration` or On Terminal using `gradle task`.

---

If you're going to create new project use `gdx-setup.jar` of latest [build](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The great solution for upgrade gradle version.

Answer (score 4):

I temporarily solve this by forcing plugin to use 2.3.3 and gradle wrapper properties file reverted to 3.3

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

and build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

comment out the google() from repositories and tell android studio 3.0 to stop reminding you to upgrade gradle plugin to 3.0.0 for your current project.

Edit: To the person above who plagiarised my answer, shame on you!

Answer (score 2):

Edit configurations -> Desktop -> In before launch change "Build" to "Build project". (use the + and - buttons).

Comment: This is actually the best answer at this date 20180718, because if you follow the wiki https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA "Running Your Project" -> "desktop" the only thing you need to change what DrLey says, this maintains the console links to errors, and you gonna miss that if you run from console. AS 3.1.3 LibGDX 1.9.8, PS: i dont use html module.

Answer (score 1):

worked with windows , in terminal you can go to the project folder and run desktop module using command .

```
gradlew desktop:run
```