# LibGDX FlappyBird

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to work my way through a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzBVTPaUUDg) and I"m stuck at the beginning.  I'm trying to learn this stuff.  Having a blast but just stuck in the gate.

build gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'FloppyDemo'
        gdxVersion = '1.6.3'
        roboVMVersion = '1.4.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.4.0'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

The Error I get:
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'FloppyDemo'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
>            https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>            https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :

Comment: show `build.gradle` file of root project also make sure you're using `gradle 4.1`

Answer (score 0):

**Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.1**

1. Update Gradle version

   Android plugin 3.0.1 requires Gradle version 4.1 or higher.
   To update Gradle manually, Find gradle folder inside your project and edit the URL in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to the following:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
   ```
2. Apply the plugin

   Add google maven repo inside buildscript tag

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
          ...
          google()       // <-- Add this 
       }

       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
       }
   }
   ```

---

Before proceeding to update, you should check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947873/libgdx-doesnt-working-after-updating-gradle-android-studio-3-0/46959125#46959125) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975883/error2-0-plugin-with-id-jetty-not-found/46977035#46977035)