# Fail to run desktop app with desktop:run LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using android studio idea for my libgdx project. I configured custom desktop configuration setting

```
Tasks: desktop:run
Gradle Project: mygame
```

Running android works fine but running this configuration brings the following error

> 9:08:42 PM: Executing task 'desktop:run'...
>
> Executing tasks: [desktop:run]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. WARNING:
>   Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation'. It will be removed at the end of 2018 Gradle now
>   uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build
>   assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This
>   behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle
>   5.0   at build_4irp102idy0ifcnkhwn53osnp$_run_closure3.doCall(D:\LibgdxProjects\Tembo\desktop\build.gradle:22)
>     (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this
>   deprecation warning.)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s 9:08:45 PM: Task execution finished 'desktop:run'.

Important details

```
Gradle version: 4.4
```

How can i fix this. I tried downgrading my gradle version but the minimim supported is 4.4

NOTE: running `gradlew desktop:run` on project root works.

Comment: what do you mean by `minimum supported is 4.4` ? , downgrade with Android gradle plugin

Comment: In android studio i can downgrade gradle to any version below 4.4 @Aryan

Comment: Can or can’t ??

Comment: Can't  . . .  sorry@Aryan

Comment: You can, just downgrade your Android Gradle plugin version to 2.3.3

Comment: check this [threaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959125/3445320) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently this version of gradle is not supported you can use version 2.3.3
There is an activity to upgrade to Gradle 4.6 which you can follow up here
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5177

Comment: Actually, Gradle 4.6  is now supported.